# to split string into possibile number of combinations

Tags: sql

.if i have a string 'A,B,C'

output be like =

|A,B,C|
|A,C,B|
|B,A,C|
|B,C,A|
|C,A,B|
|C,B,A|

It means if your string has 3 string with comma seperated that mean we have to get the 3! ( 3 factorial ) is the number of rows . 
We required the output like above

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags/title from the question here; please [edit] your question to (re)tag what you are actually using, and only that. Also *explain* the problem. Demonstrate what you've tried, and tell us what what you have didn't work, or what about what you've researched you didn't understand.

Comment: Can the number of delimited values vary as well? Could you have `'Y,Z'` or `'D,E,F,G'`, for example?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a set based approach.  Assuming you are starting off with the following table:

```
val
---
A
B
C
```

We can try this join approach:

```sql
SELECT t1.val + ',' + t2.val + ',' + t3.val AS output
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t2.val <> t1.val
INNER JOIN yourTable t3
    ON t3.val <> t2.val AND t3.val <> t1.val
ORDER BY t1.val, t2.val, t3.val;
```

Comment: can we do this dynamic through procedure . because if 4 rows then above query will not work and we have to add one more join . can we do it dynamic through procedure

Comment: @Larnu That damn bot...gets me every time!

Comment: It's like I [knew this was coming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74899363/to-split-string-into-possibile-number-of-combinations#comment132178393_74899363)... If you want a dynamic solution, you must certainly need to tell us what RDBMS you are using, @shubham . You should also have given more than one example in your question, so that it's not assumed that you would always need 6 rows.

Comment: thank you for your quick response . i need it in sql server

Comment: So as I originally asked, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74899363/edit) your question appropriately, @shubham .

Answer (score 0):

If you would do this with SQL, then a simple way is to use cross join, eliminating only the repeating series. You didn't tag your database but many databases support things like values (), generate_series() and such. This is valid for SQL Server:

```
with myTable (x) as 
  (select * from (values('A'),('B'),('C')) t(x))
select * from myTable t1, myTable t2, myTable t3
where t1.x <> t2.x and t1.x <> t3.x and t2.x <> t3.x
  order by t1.x, t2.x, t3.x;
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/R0QFODW7)

You are starting with a string 'A,B,C' then you could use string_split():

```
with myTable (x) as 
  (select * from string_split('A,B,C',','))
select * from myTable t1, myTable t2, myTable t3
where t1.x <> t2.x and t1.x <> t3.x and t2.x <> t3.x
  order by t1.x, t2.x, t3.x;
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/qlpvYaBE)

Comment: can we do this dynamic through procedure . because if 4 rows then above query will not work and we have to add one more join . can we do it dynamic through procedure

Comment: @shubham, yes you can. Check sp_executeSql.

Comment: @shubham - if you take the time to read the duplicate question and related answers, you will find a very elegant solution that does not require dynamic SQL.

Comment: @Alex, you don't need to comment twice, one is enough to signify it is an elegant solution "if you want the result as a string" and then you don't need dynamic sql.